# Recursion in dict

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I have a nested `dict` which looks like this:

[image]

There are multiple nestings within the key `children`. I would like to capture the key `branch` whenever the key `children` is present. Because there are multiple `children`, I would like to do this for each child. Ofcourse, each child can also have further `children`. This nesting can go upto 7 levels.

To achieve this, I could either write a boneheaded 7-for loop method or use recursion. So I gave recursion a shot and came up with the following code:

```
def GatherConcepts(header):
    if 'children' in header.keys():
        if len(header['children']) > 0:
            if 'branch' in header.keys():
                concepts.append(header['handle'])
                if 'children' in header.keys():
                    for j in range(0, len(header['children'])):
                        GatherConcepts(header['children'][j])
            else:
                for i in range(0,len(header['children'])):
                    GatherConcepts(header['children'][i])
```

The problem with this code is that it gives me only 2 levels (because I'm calling the function itself 2 times, thereby not using recursion properly), not 7.

How can I improve this to get all the levels?

Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show an example of the input (the one provided would do) and the output you would expect from it?

Comment: It looks like the top-level dict has `children`, but no `branch` (unless I'm reading that output incorrectly) ...

Comment: Also, FWIW, `key in some_dict.keys()` will be less efficient (significantly on python2.x) than `key in some_dict`.

Comment: The second `if 'children' in header.keys()` is unnecessary. You already tested that at the top of the function, it's not going to change.

Comment: I've updated the image to provide more clarity on the data I'm dealing with

Comment: Note that there is also https://codereview.stackexchange.com for improving working code.

Comment: @Patthebug It would be better if you posted plain text instead of an image, so we can copy it.

Comment: @kojiro It's not working code.

Comment: Shouldn't `header['handle']` be `header['branch']['handle']`?

Comment: I've added a link to the sample data set

Comment: @Barmar - I don't want the `branch's` `handle`, I want the `child's` `handle`. I agree that the second `if` statement is unnecessary. I included that only to to try more stuff.

Comment: What if the element has `branch` but not `handle`? The top-level dict doesn't have `handle`.

Comment: Looking at the dict more carefully now, I think the `branch` handle may be unnecessary too. I'm only after the `handle` field in every child. I only want a final list of all the `handle` present inside `children`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117236/discussion-between-patthebug-and-barmar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some unnecessary redundancies. If I understand you correctly, you need to add the handles to the list separately from the recursion, because you want to test `branch` in the parent.

```
def GatherConcepts(header):
    if 'children' in header and 'branch' in header:
        for child in header['children']:
            concepts.append(child['handle'])
            GatherConcepts(child)
```

You don't need to test the length of `header['children']` -- if it's zero then the loop will just not do anything.

Comment: I don't want the branch's handle, I want the child's handle. I agree that the second if statement is unnecessary. I included that only to to try more stuff.

Comment: This code works well for the most part, but it gives me the `branch's` `handle`, whereas I want the `child's` `handle`.

Comment: I took that out 20 minutes ago, now it gives the child's handle.

Comment: But only if the child also has a branch. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Ahh, sorry, looks like I was using the wrong piece of code. Your code works perfectly, thanks a lot :).

Comment: I think I now understand you. `branch` is in the parent, and then you gather all its children's handles, and also recurse into the children.

Comment: Yes, exactly. `branch` is in the parent and then I have to gather all its `children`. The code that you have provided seems to work well :). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get recursion correctly, you can use this simple template for it:

```
def recursive(variable):
    if something:
        # base step
        return somethingelse
    else:
        # recursive step
        return recursive(somethingelse)
```

In your case, you can try something like this:

```
def gather_concepts(header):
    # recursive step
    if 'branch' in header and 'handle' in header:
        concepts.append(header['handle'])
    if 'children' in header:
        for child in header['children']:
            return gather_concepts(child)
    # base step
    else:
        return
```

You should tweak this code under your needs though, because I haven't tested it myself.

Comment: Looking at the dict more carefully now, I think the `branch's` `handle` may be unnecessary too. I'm only after the `handle` field in every `child`. I only want a final list of all the `handle` present inside `children`.